# How to get user input right when running a shell script?

Tags: shell

For example, if i have a shell program "shell1" and run "./shell1 hello world", how can I store the hello world in a variable? If I try to use read, it only accepts user input after I run ./shell1 first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to **parameters** being passed to the script.

To capture them use `$1` for the first parameter, `$2` for the second, `$3` for the third, and so forth. Use `"$@"` to capture all parameters into a single variable.

For example, try adding the following to your script:

```
param1="$1"
param2="$2"
echo "Param1 is $param1, Param2 is $param2"

allParams="$@"
echo "All params are: $allParams"
```

Take a look at [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Positional Parameters](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html) for more information.